# Dropdown to open instantly

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

How can I make the dropdown open instantly without any delays? At the moment when you click to open a dropdown it has a half second delay till it opens. That's caused by setTimeout(function() with 500ms delay. I had to use that in order to make a second dropdown open only when the first one is closed... I just couldn't think of anything better and because of that when you open a dropdown it doesn't open instantly :(
I wanted it to be instant but open smoothly with 500ms speed and close with a 300ms speed.

Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
$(".click").on("click", function(evt) {
       evt.stopPropagation();
      var navItem = $(this);

      if (navItem.hasClass("is-active")) {
        navItem.removeClass("is-active");
        navItem.parent().find(".showup").slideUp(300);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
        },500);
      }else{
        $(".is-active").removeClass("is-active");
        $(".showup").slideUp(300);
        setTimeout(function() {
          navItem.addClass("is-active");
          navItem.parent().find(".showup").slideDown(500);
          $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
          $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
        },500);
      }
    });
    $(".showup").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function(evt) {
    $(".is-active").parent().find(".showup").slideUp(300);
    $(".is-active").toggleClass("is-active");
    if ($(".main-container").hasClass("black-bg")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".main-container").toggleClass("black-bg");
      }, 500);
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

nav {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

.nav-content {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ccc;
}

.top-bar-section {
    float: left;
}
.top-bar-section a.active {
    background: #f00;
}


.showup {
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 30px 15px 30px 20px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

li.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
li.nav-item a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
.black-bg {
    background: #000;
}
.is-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 1</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 1.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 2</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 2.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 3</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 3.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 4</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 4.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

I Change only for script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
$(".click").on("click", function(evt) {
       evt.stopPropagation();
      var navItem = $(this);

      if (navItem.hasClass("is-active")) {
        navItem.removeClass("is-active");
        navItem.parent().find(".showup").slideUp(300);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
        },200);
      }else{
        $(".is-active").removeClass("is-active");
        $(".showup").slideUp(200);
        setTimeout(function() {
          navItem.addClass("is-active");
          navItem.parent().find(".showup").slideDown(500);
          $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
          $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
        },200);
      }
    });
    $(".showup").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function(evt) {
    $(".is-active").parent().find(".showup").slideUp(300);
    $(".is-active").toggleClass("is-active");
    if ($(".main-container").hasClass("black-bg")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".main-container").toggleClass("black-bg");
      }, 500);
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

nav {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

.nav-content {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ccc;
}

.top-bar-section {
    float: left;
}
.top-bar-section a.active {
    background: #f00;
}


.showup {
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 30px 15px 30px 20px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

li.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
li.nav-item a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
.black-bg {
    background: #000;
}
.is-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 1</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 1.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 2</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 2.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 3</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 3.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 4</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 4.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```

Comment: Your example still has 200ms delay and it should be instant. Thank you.